# Display lines of data using List or Dictionary?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a .txt file (with several lines of data) in the following format:
last name,first name,rate,hours,gross pay

I need to create a program that will open that file (I think I have this part, below) and display each line of the file as a comma-delimited. What should I use? A list or a dictionary?

I know that dictionaries can only support two items, but these lines have 5 fields, would a list work better? And what would be the best way to go about the code? Thank you in advance!

```
def main():
    f = open("payroll.txt", "r")
```

Comment: Dictionaries can store a lot more than 2 elements... You would probably use an array of dictionaries, or an array of objects if that would actually help your program be easier to understand.

Comment: Please provide a few (two or three) lines of example input, and the corresponding output that you'd like to produce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input format is not clear. If your source data file contains comma-separated values, you probably want to use the csv library.

Simple example:

```
import csv
f = open ("payroll.txt", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f)
for line in reader:
    # each line is a list of values, proceed from here
```

alternatively, you can use the DictReader:

```
import csv
f = open ("payroll.txt", "r")
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
for line in reader:
    # each line is a dictionary of key:val pairs, keys taken from the 
    # header row
```

If your input format is not comma-separated, you'll need to give an example of what exactly you're reading, and how you want to display it.

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you!
  
  6 def main():
  7     f = open("payroll.txt", "r")
  8     lis = {}
  9     for line in f:
 10         employee = line.rstrip().split(",")
 11         if len(employee) > 1:
 12             emp = {}
 13             print(employee)
 14             emp["Last Name"]=employee[0]
 15             emp["First Name"]=employee[1]
 16             emp["Rate"]=float(employee[2])
 17             emp["Hours"]=float(employee[3])
 18             emp["Gross Pay"]=float(employee[4])
 19             lis[len(lis)]=emp
 20             print(lis)
 21 
 22 main()